# What is the correct syntax for manually setting up one way binding in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I read the documentation as well as the source but am still confused by both.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Ember.Binding(to, from).oneWay().connect(obj)` is how you'd directly create one however there is an alias `Ember.oneWay(obj, to, from)` which does the same thing .. an example usage:

```
App.aObject = Ember.Object.create({
    val: "blah blah"
});

App.bObject = Ember.Object.create({
    val: ""
});

Ember.oneWay(App, 'bObject.val', 'aObject.val');

Ember.get('App.bObject.val'); // => "blah blah"
```

You can capture that Ember.oneway() into a variable to use for manual disconnecting the binding later but usually I just use Ember's behind the scenes sorcery to create the binding binding creation by ending the value in 'Binding', so we end up with:

```
App.aObject = Ember.Object.create({
    val: "blah blah"
});

App.bObject = Ember.Object.create({
    valBinding: Ember.Binding.oneWay('App.aObject.val');
});

Ember.get('App.bObject.val'); // => "blah blah"
```

Comment: Awesome, answers my question exactly. For anyone else reading I think @chrixian meant to write Ember.oneWay( ... )

Comment: No I meant `Ember.Binding.oneWay` ... that way ember can set up the creation of the property using the given property name minus 'Binding'

Comment: word.. this is so weird. So in the case of declaring bindings after both objects have been instantiated, Ember.Binding.oneWay did not work while the alias you mentioned Ember.oneWay worked. Ember.oneway the lowercase version threw an error